# Alphas are "blurry" when sculpting?

Tags: transparency, sculpting

So all my alphas when I apply them to a model with plenty of multi-res levels just come out looking "blurry". I've used Zbrush before with these alphas, and they turned out awesome but in blender they aren't working so well. So any help on how to resolve this would be great.

I've already messed with the strength, but that didn't seem to help.

[image: The blur.]

Comment: Default uv-sphere with 5 multires level should let you achieve a result similar to this: http://i.imgur.com/Jic6dI1.jpg that looks quite good. Perhaps you have enabled some particular option. I would suggest to open a new file and try without changing any default parameter. (enable smooth shading to your object)

Comment: Still getting terrible results maybe its the alpha's I'm using. Here is another one I tried that also gives me terrible results. http://www.filedropper.com/weave01

Comment: Ok I might have a breakthrough here. Okay so the terrible results I was getting was from an un-uv mapped cube that I multi-ressed. I got some good results now by just using a circle, uv unwrapping, and multi-ressing now its pretty good looking. I'll experiment more, but I think I got it.

Comment: Here's the link to my blendfile: (blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/443) see if you can work with it.

Comment: Yeah as far as I can tell Carlo after looking at the file you uploaded it works just fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit* - After reviewing comments it was just a weird occurance that I cannot re-create. Multi-ressing a cube and than sculpting it works just fine!

Comment: In which sense "need to have some geometry" ? Why a cube is not considered geometry? This is the default cube with multires and it still looks fine: http://i.imgur.com/KghlTIa.jpg I think that the reason must be somewhere else...don't know, maybe you have mirror/polar sculpting enabled...did you check that?

Comment: Hm I must of done something I double checked to make sure and your right things are working fine now. Well I guess I shouldn't jump to conclusions and just restart Blender, and check myself.

Comment: No problem! Anyway it would be interesting to discover what setting led to that particular situation. I would suggest to upload it on http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Well If I can somehow re-create it I'll upload it to that site. Otherwise things seem to be working a bit better. http://i.imgur.com/GBINh1z.png

Comment: Good, anyway you don't need to unwrap or assign texture to the geometry tu be able to sculpt on it.